# jQuery each index starting from 2

Tags: jquery

The code I have below counts from 1 and upwards (1,2,3,4,5) etc

How could I do this so it starts from 2? i.e. 2,3,4,5

```
$('.section .next').each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: Indexing is 0 based...

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to skip the first element, or simply start indexing from `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it.. well almost :)

Make it `+2` instead of `+1`.. since index begins with 0.

```
$('.section .next').each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + (index + 2));
});
```